Can I report future income on credit card applications?
I want to apply for some credit cards (specifically from Scotiabank) but I have no income right now. I got a job offer and accepted it and will be starting in 50 days, can I report this as my income?

To answer the question, it would probably depend on how the question or application is phrased. My guess is that it's phrased in a way to get your current income (which is what they want), in which case you could not put future income that has not been earned yet. Otherwise, it could be considered fraud which would be a crime in most countries.
However...
Why not just wait until you actually start the job and then you don't have a problem? You shouldn't be using the cards until you can pay them off anyway - that's how you get into a debt spiral, constantly paying off your previous month's spending and never having anything left over.
At worst you can apply with your current income (if any) and then add your actual income once you get the job to try and get better credit terms.
Don't get into the habit of spending money you don't have yet.


"Why not just wait until you actually start the job and then you don't have a problem? You shouldn't be using the cards until you can pay them off anyway" -- OP has necessary expenses (e.g., food) to pay for before the new job starts and presumably has savings with which to do so. What can be purchased with cash can usually also be purchased with a card and paid off promptly. There are reasons to get and use a card other than "spending money you don't have yet". 2. "apply with your current income (if any)" -- OP said "I have no income right now".

